# Upgrade from EE1 to EE2 is causing some issues with Matrix

Tags: matrix

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'is_draft' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT row_id, col_id_9 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 20 AND
>   entry_id = 54 AND is_draft = 0 ORDER BY row_order ASC LIMIT 100
>
> Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php
>
> Line Number: 2808

This is the error I am receiving. I made a mistake when moving over fields where I was using the nGen File Field, so I don't know if that is adding to the issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you visit the Matrix field settings page? That should fix this.  If so, and you are still receiving this error, please email your Super Admin and PHPMyAdmin details to support@pixelandtonic.com, include the link to this thread, and we'll get this fixed up for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for making that error go away are on the old P&T GetSatisfaction site: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/matrix_2_5_upgrade_error

Answer (score 0):

It might be related but had the exact issue yesterday going from 2.3 to 2.5. 
I updated the modules first and the error was because the latest matrix requires 2.4 minimum, updated EE to 2.5.5 and problem went away.